# What can possibly have broken all the lowercase letters (but not caps) in my terminal?

Tags: macos, bash, unicode, nano

Look at this incredible screenshot. I’m editing a commit message in Nano, within iTerm (an OS X terminal). I had just pulled changes from the master branch at `git@github.com:Compass/compass.git`

[image: crazy looking terminal]

Please note how all the capital letters display fine, but no lowercase letters do!

This persisted even after I closed Nano. I had to close the terminal tab.

My question is… how is that possible? What "feature" of which software does this?

Comment: I've seen that recently in `xterm`. I was able to get back to normal characters by echoing some VT100/xterm control sequence. I don't remember the exact details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are VT100 line drawing characters.

You can reproduce it with `echo -e '\033(0'` and exit the mode with `echo -e '\033(B'`.

Alternatively, `reset` will reset the terminal and go back to normal.